Elapsed Time in QEP returned from sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats is different from the one in Actual Execution Plan returned by SSMS
I am trying to use the LAST_QUERY_PLAN_STATS property to save the QEP Actual of each executed statement in my repository,
using DMV sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats I am able to intercept it and save it without any problems.
However, when I open one of them to check the elapsed time in the properties tab,
I find an elapsed times different from the ones found in sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats and in the QEP Actual requested at run time.
I have reproduced it with a simple script and talked about it here, but would like to know if anybody has already experienced this situation.
When I run this script
--My script
--set statistics time on
SELECT TOP 50001 *
FROM [dbo].[MyBigTable]

I got this statistics time info
enter image description here and this Actual QEP
When I retrieved the QEP from  sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats using this script:
select
   [qt].[text],
   [query_plan] = (SELECT TOP 1 [query_plan] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats (a.[plan_handle])),
   [last_elapsed_time] = a.[last_elapsed_time] / 1000.0,
   a.[last_execution_time]
from (
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
WHERE creation_time > '2024-07-01 08:00:00') a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.[plan_handle]) t ) qt
WHERE qt.[text] LIKE '--My script%'
order by 4 desc

This is the QEP, with the strange Elapsed Time, that I got:
dm_exec_query_plan_stats QEP
We can see that the two QEP are identical so I don't get why they have different Elapsed Time.
Do you have any ideas?

I've approved it since you made all the requested changes, but to be honest this might be a better fit for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Didn't Erland already give you an explanation - from Microsoft, no less - for why QueryTimeStats does not reflect the same elapsed time in the DMV vs. execution plan?
